# Adding NetCDF files to Mosaic - no coordinate system

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, netcdf, image-mosaic

I have some NetCDF files that are displaying correctly in ArcGIS using the 'Make NetCDF Raster Layer'. The properties show an undefined spatial reference, but reads the eastings and northings to put it in the correct spatial location.

However when I try and add these netCDF files to a mosaic dataset, it states that the data does not have a valid coordinate system. I've attempted to force the coordinate system onto the data when adding to the mosaic, but it still fails.

Any ideas?